# Upgrading gradle breaks exoplayer on build, can't find core or dash

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, exoplayer

Android studio

```
Gradle version: 4.1
Android plugin version: 3.0.1
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.4'
```

Build works fine. Upgrade to these versions:

```
Gradle version: 4.6
Android plugin version: 3.2.1
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.4' //unchanged
```

Build fails with these messages:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.4
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.8.4
```

I've been stuck on this for a day. I can't find any reason why it should work with the old version, but not the new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add the following line to allprojects repositories.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/' } //new line
    }
}
```

Apparently, Exoplayer is no longer in JCenter. But, the files are still in bintray.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find explanation and temporary solution for this problem

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5225

Answer (score 0):

you add project build.gradle

```
repositories {
google()
jcenter()
}
```

and add

```
compileOptions {
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: Do you use proxy ?
turn on proxy.